# Android google services plugin version conflict

Tags: android, gradle

I recently upgraded Android Studio to 3.1 and I am tuck with version conflict problem.My **Gradle** version is 4.4 and **Andoid plugin** version is 3.0.0. I tried changing it to 3.1.1.It gets reverted back to the previous version mumber. It is getting confusing for me,so your help is needed. When syncing I get the following message in the Build.

**Version Conflict:**

```
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2.
```

build.gradle/app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.globemaster.samples"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: try with changing  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0' version to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 and synch

Comment: isnt the latest 3.1.1

Comment: Yes. 3.1.1 is the latest.. but since you telling that the version is getting reverted back, just try with 3.0.1 and then try again with 3.1.1

Comment: in some answers i have seen plugin at the bottom of dependency.Could that be also an issue as I am placing it on top

Comment: i don't think that matters.. Anyway I was using  same 3.1 android studio with 3.2.1 google service and  3.0.1 gradle which i recently updated to 3.1.1 which got synched without any issue.. just try with 3.0.1 is its working and then with 3.1.1  and see if it works

Comment: @jobin Do you have any libraries in your project that is using google service 11.4.2 instead of 15.0 ?.

Comment: No.. i'm using all 15.0.0 libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move this line at last
**apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.globemaster.samples"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //
    //
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

At the bottom of the (app)build.gradle script and rebuild the project.

> **Note:-**  I think that it has to do something with referencing
>   dependencies that have not yet been created. Something like calling a
>   variable before you even declare it

Comment: How does this make a difference?

Comment: @YashaswiNP  I think that it has to do something with referencing dependencies that have not yet been created. Something like calling a variable before you even declare it.

Comment: @YashaswiNP Are you the one posted this question?.

Answer (score 0):

Pls add below code in your app build **gradle.file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

Change your classpath to 3.1.1

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
```

And apply plugin after dependencies in app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```